# Retrieve image from database in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, multer

I made a file upload and saving it's path in mongodb and want to display that image in html here is my code of upload file

```
route.post('/dashboard/upload',ensureAuthenticated,(req,res) => {
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
        // console.log(files.file_thumbnail.type);
        if(files.file_thumbnail.type !== 'image/jpeg' ){
            console.log("File is not image");
            res.render('upload');
        } else {

            var oldpath = files.file_thumbnail.path;
            var newpath = '../uploads/' + files.file_thumbnail.name;
            fs.rename(oldpath, newpath, function (err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            // console.log(fields.file_name);
            console.log('File uploaded successfully!');
            res.render('upload');
            var newfile = new file({
                caption : fields.caption,
                file_thumbnail : newpath    
            });
            newfile.save()
                .then(chllange => {
                    console.log("New File Added");
                })
                .catch(err => console.log(err));
            });

        }
    });
});
```

here is my show image code

```
route.get('/dashboard/files',(req,res) => {
    file.find({},['file_thumbline','caption'],{sort:{_id:-1}}, (err, data) => {
        console.log(data);
        res.render('files', {file: data});
    });

});
```

and here is my image html code

```
<img src="<%= file.file_thumbnail %>" alt="Image">
<p><%= file.caption %></p>
```

error is after render code it shows alter text and in inspect element shows img src(unknown)

**Edit**
in show image code in

```
console.log(data);
```

it returnes all json data but when I get

```
console.log(data.caption);
```

it returns undefined

Answer (score 0):

> Edit in show image code in
>
> console.log(data);
>
> it returnes all json data but when I get
>
> console.log(data.caption);
>
> it returns undefined

You are receiving an array from mongo. So if you want to access it you need to select an item ie. data[0].caption

Comment: hoolllyyy shhit 
thank you so much man and i'm thinking why is this sending Json data in [ ] brackets :').
Thank you so much

Comment: but now in image it shows alt tag and when i open url of image http://127.0.0.1:3000/uploads/html.jpg it says Cannot GET /uploads/html.jpg

Answer (score -1):

Dont u have to close it in the image tag like that?

```
<img src="<%= file.file_thumbnail %>" alt="Image">
```

Comment: yeah It's just typo edited thanks mate but error is still same

Comment: Okay maybe u can show us the output of
```
console.log(data);
```

Comment: [ { _id: 5c739b995b75692544ed623d,
    caption: 'HTML',
    file_thumbnail: '../uploads/html.jpg',
    __v: 0 } ]